# In AngularJS how can I data bind a model from one controller with another?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have two `ngController`s in one `ngApp`. I'd like to data bind the model from one controller with another.

Here's an example of my controllers:

1. ViewUsers: Is a list view of users
2. UserDetail: Is a detailed view of a single user

When the user clicks on a `userRow(model:$scope.users[n])` in `ViewUsers`, it's calling a global function that creates a new instance of `UserDetail`.

But I want to send the `$scope.users[n]` in the constructor of `UserDetail` or something by reference so any changes to the `model`in my `UserDetail` controller will be reflected in the `userRow` from the `ViewUsers` controller.

So for example, when you change the name in the detailed view, it'll be relected in the list view on the side.

Are `services` the route I need to go? Or `$watch`?

Any advice would be appreciated, Thanks!

Comment: Refer great tutorial "AngularJS controller communication" here http://onehungrymind.com/angularjs-communicating-between-controllers/

Comment: Hmm, thanks for this. Although the problem is that I'm creating a new controller dynamically; not written into the html. Maybe i'll try creating the new controller, then broadcasting via rootscope.

Comment: It can be another solution, yes

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Another approuch to use scope which is parent for both of your scopes or $rootScope.

Also, see [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20963444/from-angularjs-how-to-pass-data-from-a-controllertemplate-to-another-controller/20963662#20963662) - there is an example how to share data between controllers.